# Deleting multiple checked items from an SQL bound checklist

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ado.net, checklistbox

So right now, I have tried the following code, however it only removes one list item. It seems that after it deletes the first item, the list refreshes and the other checked item does not get deleted. How can I go around this so that all the checked items are deleted from the DB Table?

```
//NewFoodInputTextBox is an ASP.NET TextBox which takes input 
//just fine and outputs status/error updates as well.
protected void DeleteFoodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int delCount = 0;
        int prevDelCount = 0;
        string status = "";
        foreach (ListItem Item in FoodChecklist.Items)
        {
            if (Item.Selected)
            {
                FoodList.Delete(); //only deletes 1 item
                prevDelCount = delCount;
                delCount += 1;
                if (delCount > prevDelCount) //printing out the deleted items
                {
                    status = status + " " + Item.ToString(); //returns all checked items normally
                }
            }
        }
        if (delCount == 0)
        {
            NewFoodInputTextBox.Text = "Nothing selected to delete";
        }
        else
        {
            NewFoodInputTextBox.Text = "Deleted the following: " + status;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
         NewFoodInputTextBox.Text = "Unexpected behavior detected";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the `Selected` items, and not the `Checked` ones. These are 2 different things (selected is the blue highlight, checked is the checkbox). Use the `Checked` property in your condition and everything should work fine.

Side note, you could also use the `CheckedItems` property of the `ListView` in your `foreach` to simplify your code.

```
foreach (ListItem Item in FoodChecklist.CheckedItems)
```